# Sentry Issue : not able to get the user email on the sentry

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sentry

I am working on JS and using in my code, I am setting the email as `Sentry.setUser(email)` where email is the object and I am getting the proper email via checking through `Sentry.getUser()` in my console but in the sentry dashboard it's not showing the email of the respective user instead it's showing only the IP.

`Sentry.setUser(email); console.log(Sentry.getUser());`

I tried the below
`Sentry.setUser(email); console.log(Sentry.getUser());`
but In the console I'm getting the user details as needed that proofs the email has been set but in the sentry it is only showing the IP address.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This is the snippet for your reference
`const scope = new Sentry.Scope();
scope.setUser(exceptionObject.userDetails);
console.log(scope.getUser());
scope.setContext("Error Details", exceptionObject.errorDetails);
Sentry.captureMessage(errorTitle, scope);`

In the above snippet the `exceptionObject.userDetails` contains the email id of the user in this format `{"email":"nitesh@gmail.com"}`
In my logs according to the 3rd line `console.log(scope.getUser());` I'm getting the details as `{"email":"nitesh@gmail.com"}` but in the sentry I am not get the
email, only IP address is shown there

Answer (score 1):

`Sentry.setUser()` doesn't take a string but an object. You likely wanna do:

```
Sentry.setUser({
  email: 'user@example.com'
})
```

or

```
Sentry.setUser({
  id: 'some-user-id'
})
```

Comment: I did that only
This is the snippet for your reference
const scope = new Sentry.Scope();
scope.setUser(exceptionObject.userDetails);
console.log(scope.getUser());
scope.setContext("Error Details", exceptionObject.errorDetails);
Sentry.captureMessage(errorTitle, scope);

In the above exceptionObject.userDetails contains the email id of the user in this format {"email":"nitesh@gmail.com"}
In my logs according to the 3rd line console.log(scope.getUser()) I'm getting the details as {"email":"nitesh@gmail.com"} but in the sentry I am not getting the
email, only IP address is shown there.

Comment: Instead of creating a new scope you need to set the user on the current scope with `Sentry.getCurrentHub().getScope().setUser()`

Comment: It's not working 
same issue is there